# Delete Query(named native Query) is not working in JPA with Hibernate specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have my named native query in orm.xml as,

```
<named-native-query name="deleteAuthTokenByToken">
    <query><![CDATA[DELETE FROM AUTH_TOKEN WHERE TOKEN=:token]]></query>
</named-native-query>
```

I'm trying to execute this query in my code as

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createNamedQuery("deleteAuthTokenByToken").setParameter("token", token).executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Entity Manager itself not creating when I have query in orm.xml, getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported
```

But the same query is working when I use createNativeQuery()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result class is missing here, It's resolved Once I changed to

```
<named-native-query name="deleteAuthTokenByTokenAndOrgId" result-class="com.modria.jpa.DO.AuthToken">
    <query><![CDATA[DELETE FROM AUTH_TOKEN WHERE TOKEN=:token AND ORG_ID=:orgId]]></query>
</named-native-query>
```